# Operator = overloading in virtual inheritance in c++

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading, base-class, virtual-inheritance

Suppose that we have a hierarchy like the one below. Do we have to call the operator = method of the virtual base class A or not?

```
class A
{ ... }

class B : virtual public A
{ ... }

class C : virtual public A
{ ... }

class D : public B, public C
{
   D& operator = (const D& other)
   {
      if(this != &other)
      {
       // A::operator = (other); is this line correct???
          B::operator = (other);
          C::operator = (other);
          ....
       }
      return *this;
    }
 }
```

Comment: depends on `B/C::operator` implementation. they may did call the `A::operator =`.

Comment: D has only two parents (B and C) do not invoke A in the copy operator (However, during construction, the most derived class has to invoke the virtual base constructor)

Answer (score 4):

Like @Emadpres stated in the comment, it depends on how `operator=` is treated in the hierarchy. If B and C utilize A's implementation of `operator=`, then you don't have to explicitly use that in D's implementation.

Keep in mind that, to keep semantics straight, you probably should use A's implementation in B and C. Trying to go all the way up the hierarchy tree when overloading is a good way to introduce tons of complexity.